# TableLayout not showing when restored from savedInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, restore, android-tablelayout

I have a tableLayout in a fragment that´s not showing anything when the information used to populate the cells is taken from the savedInstanceState bundle from OnCreateVIew()

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = initializeViews(inflater,container);

        if (savedInstanceState!= null){
            cellsTextArrayList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("extractedTextEt");
            for (String word: cellsTextArrayList){
                addRow(word);
            }
        }

            return rootView;

    }




private void addRow(String word){
        final TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_layout, null);
        EditText actualCell = view.findViewById(R.id.cell_text);
        actualCell.setText(word);

        tr.addView(view);
        tableLayout.addView(tr);

    }


@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
    {
        cellsTextArrayList.add("first");
        cellsTextArrayList.add("second");
        cellsTextArrayList.add("third");
        outState.putStringArrayList("extractedTextEt", cellsTextArrayList);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

The cellsTextArrayList is being restored from the savedInstanceState object, the addRow() method is the one that´s not working. I ran the code on an Activity and it worked so I think this has to do with the Fragment lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

using onActivityCreated in fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's state here
    }
}
```

and then in the activity, you have to save the fragment's instance in onSaveInstanceState() and restore in onCreate().

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MyFragment 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            //Restore the fragment's instance
            mMyFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "myFragmentName");
            ...
        }
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        //Save the fragment's instance
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "myFragmentName", mMyFragment);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I´m still having the same problem